# Setting property of subclass of UIStoryboardSegue [optional animation on modal segue]

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I created a subclass of `UIStoryboardSegue` in order to achieve a modal segue with optional animation.

(subclass of `UIStoryboardSegue`):
.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ModalSegue_OptionalAnimation : UIStoryboardSegue
@property (readwrite) BOOL withAnimation;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "ModalSegue_OptionalAnimation.h"

@implementation ModalSegue_OptionalAnimation

-(void) perform{
    BOOL _withAnimation_Va = self.withAnimation;
    [[[self sourceViewController] navigationController] pushViewController:[self   destinationViewController] animated:_withAnimation_Va];
}

@end
```

But I am unsure now how to call this property from the outside.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segue_qVC_to_cVC_checkAnswer"]) {
        CheckAnswerViewController *cVC = [segue destinationViewController];

        if(segue_QVC_ISEXAM) {
            //Something like this:
            //segue.withAnimation = NO;
            //Settings the property to NO is like 'I dont animation when performing the segue'
        }
    ....
```

In my storyboard I already set the segue to custom with the just created class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segue_qVC_to_cVC_checkAnswer"]) {
    CheckAnswerViewController *cVC = [segue destinationViewController];

    if(segue_QVC_ISEXAM) {
        ModalSegue_OptionalAnimation *customSegue = (ModalSegue_OptionalAnimation *)segue;
        customSegue.withAnimation = NO;

        //Something like this:
        //segue.withAnimation = NO;
        //Settings the property to NO is like 'I dont animation when performing the segue'
    }
....
```

Comment: Thanks, thats working just fine!
Althought I had to use `[[self sourceViewController] presentModalViewController:[self destinationViewController] animated:_withAnimation_Va];` instead the one from above.